# ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR: column "recipes.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Im having trouble getting this method to work with heroku, when trying to load the page i get the above error message. I have had some help in a previous post but it seems the re-factoring has not worked. From what i have read i need to include all columns of the model in the search and group..is that correct? The method and schema follows

Method

```
def self.popular_recipes
  select('recipes.*, count(*) AS dish_count').
  group('dish_name').
  order('dish_count DESC')
 end
```

Schema

```
create_table "recipes", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "dish_name"
t.string   "difficulty"
t.text     "preperation_time"
t.datetime "created_at",          :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at",          :null => false
t.integer  "user_id"
t.string   "avatar_file_name"
t.string   "avatar_content_type"
t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
t.integer  "country_id"
t.string   "category"
t.text     "description"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're selecting `recipes.*` which confuses PostgreSQL.

Say you have 10 unique dish_names in a `recipes` table with 500 records. A `GROUP BY dish_name` clause would result in only 10 rows returned. So if you ask for `recipes.*`, how is Postgres supposed to know how to fill in the other columns for the 10 rows?

Do this instead:

```
def self.popular_recipes
  select('dish_name, count(*) AS dish_count').
  group('dish_name').
  order('dish_count DESC')
 end
```

Note that MySQL behaves differently in this situation (no error), and would give you one row back for every `dish_name`, but which row that would be is essentially undefined.